# PHP Error- extension_dir does not exists /usr/lib/php5/20090626 even though that folder is present

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I installed PHP 5.3.x in my Ubuntu 12.04 Server using apt-get.

Now when I am trying to run a specific PHP script I get this error message--

"extension_dir does not exists /usr/lib/php5/20090626"

But when I logged in via SSH and went to the above path- it does exist and also contains some PHP extensions.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: View this link may be help you http://wiki.helioviewer.org/wiki/Compiling_PHP_from_source_on_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

use `chown` command for changing the ownership of the folder to the php user.

**EDIT:**

[Please visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)

**The user running apache is also running php**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the php file is not accessible to browser.You should change the file permission .You can use `chown` and change the file permission like `777`